# column to row transformation

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following table names ETEST with col1 and col2 as column names.

```
  col1  col2
  ====    ==== 
  eid   101
  name  abc
  age   30
  eid   102
  name  xyz
  age   40
```

The values eid, name and can be repeated,I want to write an sql query to display data like below:

```
eid name  age
101 abc   30
102  xyz  40
```

I tried something like below but that's not works for all the records.

```
 SELECT MAX(DECODE(a.col1,'eid',a.col2 )) eid,
  MAX(DECODE(a.col1,'name',a.col2 )) name ,
  MAX(DECODE(a.col1,'age',a.col2 )) age
FROM
  (SELECT rownum,
    last_value(col1 ignore nulls) over (order by rownum) col1,
    last_value(col2 ignore nulls) over (order by rownum) col2
  FROM etest
  ORDER BY rownum
  )a;
```

Please note , there can be n number of entries for eid,name and age in col1 of the above table.

Please  help.
Regards,
MKS

Comment: your database structure makes no sense, how are we to know that "xyz" relates to "102" and not "101"? There must be another column on that table.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier , the corresponding values for eid,name and age should be selected by the sql query..

Comment: sorry still don't understand, what logic says that "xyz" should show for "101"?, is it purely the order of the rows in the table? if so then you are in a heap of trouble.

Comment: Its order of rows which is fixed.

Comment: sorry but your database design is incorrect, having a design based on the order of columns is just plain wrong. You could write a query to do what you ask but it would be of no practical use.

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant way of rewriting columns to rows is making use of the `pivot` statement. Such a code would look like something like this:

```
select *
  from etest
  pivot
   ( min(col2)
     for col1 in ('eid', 'name', 'age')
   )
```

But I agree with the former statement: the database design is doubtfull. You can never be sure that the choosen `eid` in one row belongs to another `name` or `age` in another row. So this solution offered is just a halfway one.